# Get activity `ViewDataBinding` field inside `Robolectric` unit test after being assigned

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am writing a Robolectric unit test which requires me to make use of the activity under test view data binding class(`ViewDataBinding`), unfortunately with no luck I am stuck with it being null inside of the unit test

inside of `MainActiviy` class:

```
...
ActivityMainBinding binding; // <-- this field returns null inside unit test
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
}
...
```

If anyone has written a test with a similar requirement please could you demonstrate an example of how you got the `ViewDataBinding` classed to be assigned before the test completed. Thanks!

> Note: I am using `Android Studio 2.2`

Comment: Do you have your code available public?

Comment: @EugenMartynov Unfortunately not, however its something thats will come in handy for future tests with Android view DataBinding & `Robolectric`

Comment: I will try to get some open source project with DataBinding and add Robolectric to it

Comment: @EugenMartynov Thanks Eugen, will appreciate that

Comment: @EugenMartynov Hey Eugen, how are things going, have you had time or any luck on this question so far?

Comment: Didn't have time, but will try today evening

Comment: @EugenMartynov Thanks Eugen, good luck

Comment: Here was my attempt for databinding in Robolectric https://github.com/emartynov/android-architecture/tree/todo-databinding. It throws completely different exception that I'm going to submit as issue to Robolectric

Comment: @EugenMartynov Wow, beautifully laid out, I really appreciate your hard work Eugen! When I have the time tonight will go through you solution and try figure out if we can get the next Robolectric issue resolved, if you would like that? Enjoy the rest of your day :)

Comment: @EugenMartynov I am looking into the `StackOverflowError` now and I believe this open issue link on Robolectric may be helpful `https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2233`, even though the solution you provided uses a `BaseAdapter` and the issue suggests its caused from using `ArrayAdapter`. It could be that each list item internally must be measured manually. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that testing with `Robolectric` version `3.1` was my issue and after upgrading to using  `Robolectric` version `3.1.4` the activities `ViewDataBinding` field was no longer returning `null`

See PR: https://github.com/emartynov/android-architecture/pull/1

Thanks to `@EugenMartynov` for your contribution towards this issue.

> Note: Used `Gradle` version `3.1` for building project, if you do decide to use `Gradle` version `3.1` and experience other issues after upgrading.Kindly look at `Gradles change logs` to update your Gradle build scripts(`build.gradle`) accordingly, before commenting other unrelated issues.